# Time Machine: Some of the files on your Mac cannot be backed up until Cloud Files syncing has completed

Tags: icloud, backup, time-machine

After upgrading to Sonoma (macOS 14.0), I'm getting "**Backup Delayed...**". In Time Machine Settings, I see the following message: "**Time Machine: Some of the files on your Mac cannot be backed up until Cloud Files syncing has completed**".

In the Finder, next to the iCloud Drive icon, I can see signs of activity.

I cannot turn off iCloud Drive, since I'm using it in a number of ways (namely to synchronize Obsidian documents between devices).

Any known workaround? I've seen on Reddit that it was an issue in the preview releases.

Did Apple mention changes to iCloud sync mechanisms that would trigger such a long synchronization process? Everything was up to date before the upgrade and I have a 1Gb Internet connection.

Comment: Update: after 4 hours, iCloud Drive has now finished its synchronization and Time Machine was able to proceed with the backup.

Comment: What may be happening: If you don't use 'optimise to iCloud', macOS will no longer allow you to have iCloud Drive files only in iCloud - they have to remain on the disk. TM could be waiting for that download to complete.

Comment: @MarcelTurcotte Comments can disappear, but answers remain. Please include your comment text ("Update after 4 hours...") as an Answer, using the Answer box below. On the SE websites (like this one), it's perfectly acceptable to answer one's own question.

Answer (score 0):

iCloud is very slow at syncing some files sometimes. I've found that sometimes an app might be using a file in iCloud which locks TimeMachine from syncing.

The best approach is to restart without restoring apps and trigger one immediately from Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Time Machine: "Some of the files on your Mac cannot be backed up until Cloud Files syncing has completed".

However, when I looked at my iCloud drive, it was in fact done syncing.

This happened after I migrated from an Intel Macbook Air to a M3 MacBook Pro.

I tried every suggestion I could find with Google Searches and nothing worked.

I finally noticed that Photoshop was missing. It somehow got automatically deleted after the migration. So I tried to run Adobe Creative Cloud to re-install Photoshop. It told me I needed to upgrade to the Apple Silicon version.
When I did that and then installed Photoshop and re-installed Dreamweaver (both Apple silicon) Time Machine backups started working immediately.

So, I think the Time Machine problem was caused by the Intel Version of Adobe Creative Cloud.